# notifyDataSetChanged() not updating list view when adding data

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am reading and adding data in `ListView` from 3 different xml feeds, the fetching process runs thrice for execute three different asynctasks.

Here is my code for `onPostExecute`,

```
if (fetchedData.isEmpty())
    fetchedData = result;
else 
    fetchedData.addAll(result);

if (sAdapter == null) {
    sAdapter = new SpecialAdapter(myapp.this, fetchedData,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);
    setListAdapter(sAdapter);
} else {
    sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

in the above code `fetchedData` is an `ArrayList`.

The above code works fine and update the listView for all 3 feeds. But once the data of all the three feeds is added in the listView, I want to add another `ArrayList` data in my `ListView`.

Which means I want to add the data if all feeds are loaded so I added `if` block,

```
if (//all feeds added in the list) {
    Log.e("added","feeds added");
    // add another ArrayList in my ListView here 
    // and update the List adapter
}
```

and this is actual code for the above `if` block,

```
if (count == feeds.length) {

    Log.e("added","feeds added");
    //adding another arrayList in list view ArrayList
    fetchedData.addAll(test.secondryArray);
    // checking if it is added  (it is added successfully
    Log.e("size of fetchedData",fetchedData.size + "");
    // update the adapter
    sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In `if` block, I added a new arraylist in my list view array list and updated the `SimpleAdapter`, but the data is not displaying in the `ListView` for some reason. I first thought that the data is not added in the `fetchedData` array from `test.secondaryArray` but that is not true because data is added successfully in `fetchedData` array but the adapter is not being updated.

here is my complete inPostExecute code,

```
if (fetchedData.isEmpty())
    fetchedData = result;
else 
    fetchedData.addAll(result);

String[] keys = { GetFeeds.KEY_TITLE, GetFeeds.KEY_DATE};
int[] ids = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

// KEY_TITLE = text1
// KEY_DATE  = text2

if (sAdapter == null) {
    sAdapter = new SpecialAdapter(myapp.this, fetchedData,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);
    setListAdapter(sAdapter);
} else {
    sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

if (count == feeds.length) {
    Log.e("added","feeds added");
    //adding another arrayList in list view ArrayList
    fetchedData.addAll(test.secondryArray);
    // checking if it is added  (it is added successfully
    Log.e("size of fetchedData",fetchedData.size + "");
    // update the adapter
    sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Why my lsitview is not being updated after I add new data after all feeds are loaded?

Edit: If I am doing the same thing outside the `if` block then it is working but not working inside if block, but this is not what I want because I want this code to execute only when all feeds are added not before that.

Comment: Are you sure the if block is being executed?

Comment: yes because `Log` messages are visible. and this is exactly why I am confused, why the adapter wouldn't updated from the `if` block ?

Comment: Are you filtering the data by any chance? And can you post your SpecialAdapter changes from SimpleAdapter, if there are any.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is like , the first time when you call this method you are trying to notify the listview by using the MainThread (UIThread) and in the second scenario (the if condition become true) you are using a background thread for notifying the listview.

Answer (score 0):

this will happen when there is no data in your `ListView` previously.
If your `ListView` is empty and you are trying to execute `notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding data in it instead of initializing your adapter then your `ListView` will stay empty.

So instead of using `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter, re-initialize it for your second array.

In your block,

```
if (count == feeds.length) {
    Log.e("added","feeds added");
    //adding another arrayList in list view ArrayList
    fetchedData.addAll(test.secondryArray);
    // checking if it is added  (it is added successfully
    Log.e("size of fetchedData",fetchedData.size + "");
    // update the adapter
    sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

replace,

```
sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

with,

```
sAdapter = new SpecialAdapter(myapp.this, fetchedData,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);
setListAdapter(sAdapter);
```